# Скрыть все ссылки кроме одной в разных блоках div

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуй, проблема такая, есть код:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
```

в каждом div c классом container мне надо скрыть .hide() все вложенные div кроме первого или не скрывать если в div c классом container cодержится только один вложенный div, подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать с использованием javascript, спасибо. Уточню что div с классом container может повторяться в любом количестве, как и количество вложенных элементов div которых всегда не менее одного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `querySelectorAll` по классу `container` складываете в переменную. Например в переменную с названием `containers`.
2. Цикл по элементам в этой переменной (`containers.forEach`)
3. На каждой итерации кладёте ещё в одну переменную узлы, найденные через `querySelectorAll` уже в конкретном элементе на текущей итерации (`el.querySelectorAll('.st_att')`). Например в переменную с названием `links`.
4. Делаем цикл по `links`. Если index элемента == 0, то `continue`, в ином случае делаем "прятанье".

---

А можно просто на *CSS*

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.st_att {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 5px;
}

.container .st_att:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
  <div class="st_att" id="st_link"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)